Closing a grps-connection when handling an exception
I'm writing an interceptor that validates messages in a grpc server and I'm running into a problem.
The general scheme is: interceptor is activated at the level of the application and validates incoming proto-messages. If it does not pass validation, I need to forward the exception further into the application so that the exception handler correctly build the response as a StatusRuntime exception and returns it to the client. Here is some sample code, it works:
@Slf4j
@GrpcGlobalServerInterceptor
public class ValidationInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  private static final String UNKNOWN_CALL_NAME = "Unknown call";
  private final GrpcExceptionResponseHandler exceptionHandler;
  private final Validator validator;

  public ValidationInterceptor(GrpcExceptionResponseHandler exceptionHandler,
                               Validator validator) {
    this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
                                                    Metadata headers,
                                                    ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    final Listener<ReqT> delegateListener = next.startCall(call, headers);
    return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<>(delegateListener) {
      @Override
      public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
        try {
          final ValidationResult validationResult = validator.validate((Message) message);

          if (!validationResult.isSuccess()) {
            exceptionHandler.handleError(call,
                new ValidationRuntimeException(
                    getMethodName(call), validationResult.getViolations())
            );
            return;
          }

          super.onMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.warn("Unexpected exception caught when validating method {}", getMethodName(call), e);
          exceptionHandler.handleError(call, e);
        }
      }
    };
  }

  private <ReqT, RespT> String getMethodName(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(call.getMethodDescriptor())
        .map(MethodDescriptor::getFullMethodName)
        .orElse(UNKNOWN_CALL_NAME);
  }
}


Handler
@GrpcAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GrpcErrorHandler {
  @GrpcExceptionHandler
  public StatusRuntimeException handleValidationRuntimeException(
      ValidationRuntimeException e) {
    String message = Optional.ofNullable(e.getMessage()).orElse(DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
    log.warn("Error {}", message, e);
    errorCounterMetrics.incrementError(e);
    return toStatusRuntimeException(e.getViolations());
  }
}


Everything works great, except for one detail. After the handleValidationRuntimeException() method has processed and returned an exception, for some reason the call() is called again on an already closed channel, which leads to an IllegalStateException
Stack trace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: call already closed
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:502)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.closeInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:216)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.close(ServerCallImpl.java:209)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCall.close(PartialForwardingServerCall.java:48)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCall.close(ForwardingServerCall.java:22)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCall$SimpleForwardingServerCall.close(ForwardingServerCall.java:39)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.metric.MetricCollectingServerCall.close(MetricCollectingServerCall.java:60)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.advice.GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.handleThrownExceptionByImplementation(GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.java:112)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.advice.GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.handleError(GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.java:82)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.error.GrpcExceptionListener.onHalfClose(GrpcExceptionListener.java:72)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.security.interceptors.AbstractAuthenticatingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(AbstractAuthenticatingServerCallListener.java:103)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.security.interceptors.DefaultAuthenticatingServerInterceptor$AuthenticatingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(DefaultAuthenticatingServerInterceptor.java:243)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.security.interceptors.ExceptionTranslatingServerInterceptor$ExceptionTranslatorServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ExceptionTranslatingServerInterceptor.java:124)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onHalfClose(Contexts.java:86)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:352)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:866)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Actually, what can be done about this? Thank you!

Which version of grpc are you using?

if you look at the first few lines of your stacktrace, you'll see the ServerCall is also expliclitly closed by MetricCollectingServerCall.close
which is called from GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.handleThrownExceptionByImplementation
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:502)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.closeInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:216)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.close(ServerCallImpl.java:209)
at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCall.close(PartialForwardingServerCall.java:48)
at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCall.close(ForwardingServerCall.java:22)
at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCall$SimpleForwardingServerCall.close(ForwardingServerCall.java:39)
at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.metric.MetricCollectingServerCall.close(MetricCollectingServerCall.java:60)
at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.advice.GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.handleThrownExceptionByImplementation(GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.java:112)
at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.advice.GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.handleError(GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.java:82)
at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.error.GrpcExceptionListener.onHalfClose(GrpcExceptionListener.java:72)
at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.advice.GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.handleError(GrpcAdviceExceptionHandler.java:82)


The solution to this problem is described here.
The basic idea is that your SimpleForwardingServerCallListener class should have a Boolean member variable that is initially false and which is set to true if the gRPC method call is closed because it doesn't pass your validation check. Then, you should also override the onHalfClose() method. In your override, you check to see if the call has been closed. If false, call super.onHalfClose(). If true, do nothing. This prevents the IllegalStateException from being thrown.
